# Blocking Task when calling vTaskDelay

Tags: c, esp32, freertos, rtos

I'm running some tasks in esp32, my problem is when im calling vTaskDelay() from a task, an other task start executing, wich is something i dont want, so how to make vTaskDelay() a blocking function please ?

Comment: this is the whole point of RTOS, to execute other stuff when you're not executing current stuff. You actually need to disable/taskdelay (all) that other stuff you don't want to execute as well.

Comment: If you need tasks to be synchronized like that then you should look into using something like a mutex, semaphore, or event set.

Comment: Have you read the ESP32 FreeRTOS manual or API reference to find if it has what you need?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why would you want everything to be blocked?

Comment: I want everything to be blocked because i have a variable that increment when im switching to an other task due to the vTaskDelay function, so what i want is blocking that task to not increment that variable

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please take a step back and describe with a broader view what you are trying to achieve. Then we can likely propose a good way of solving your problem. At the moment, you seem stuck with an approach where you have to fight the RTOS.